# What happens between Application#onCreate and Activity#onCreate?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm seeing 200ms or more latency between `MyApplication#onCreate` and `MyActivity#onCreate`. Does anything significant happen in that interval?

Comment: A lot.  They're different concepts, in fact there's no promise that an activity will ever be created when an application is started-  it could be started for a service or broadcast.

Comment: I was thinking of the case where the Application was started with an Intent for MyActivity, but you're right, I shouldn't assume that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation of `Application#onCreate` ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate())), it is called before any Activity/Service/Receiver objects are created.

This means that after `Application#onCreate` the Activity (MyActivity in your case) is instantiated and only then can `Activity#onCreate` be called.

EDIT: Based on your implementation, even the call to `super.onCreate()` in MyActivity would add to the time interval.

Comment: You can look through the code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java). In general it restores state, populates fragments and notifies the Application that the Activity has been created.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see that this also results in calling the Fragments' onActivityCreated.

Answer (score 0):

## Application onCreate() :

Called before the first components of the application starts

## Activity onCreate() :

Called then the activity is created. Used to initialize the activity, for example create the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Application onCreate() :
Called only once when application start. if you kill app then open app. it will call again.

Activity onCreate() :
Called then the activity is created. it you re-open activity it will call again but Application onCreate will call only once within application.